# Is missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: xamarin

I have a xamarin project that uses some components that are not recognized.

When I try to compile this project it gives the following error:

Error CS0246: The type or namespace name "UIKit" can not be found (is it missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error CS0246: The name of the "CoreLocation" type or namespace can not be found (is it missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Anyone have any ideas to solve this?

Comment: What type of project is it? 1) It would need to be a Xamarin.iOS application/library/binding project to reference UIKit/CoreLocation..... 2) Is Xamarin.iOS installed in Visual Studio...

Comment: Hi, you should detail explain your problem. EX: What target you want to archieve (get location in Xamarin.IOS)? Which you have done in project with some code or image? Last is to show error info .

Comment: I have the following projects: PontoCachoeiro, PontoCachoeiro.Android and PontoCachoeiro.iOS. The error appears in the PontoCachoeiro project

Comment: your shared project should not have any references to iOS specific code or libraries.  You need to remove any iOS specific libraries/nuget/components